# Cygnus only presists data on MySql database if Flume is run manually

Tags: mysql, flume, fiware, fiware-cygnus

So i had a problem with te presistance of the data on MySql databases before ( [Cygnus not presisting data on MySql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30511082/cygnus-not-presisting-data-on-mysql-database/) ) and as you can see the problem was partially resolved. I'm asking another question because this is somewhat of a different topic inside of the question.

As you can see by the question i asked before, **the problem was that the Cygnus was running but not starting any Flume component (any source, channel or sink)** .
And i started the flume agent by doing:

```
/usr/cygnus/bin/cygnus-flume-ng agent --conf /usr/cygnus/conf/ -f /usr/cygnus/conf/agent_a1.conf -n cygnusagent -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console
```

If i did this all problems were solved and the values were presisted on the tables. But once i killed the process or exited the ssh connection (I'm working on a cloud) the values stop being presisted.

You can see the log, data and scripts i'm using in the link i provided up above.

Answer (score 0):

Now your are trying to run Cygnus as a service, we need properly cnfigured the `cygnus_instance_<id>.conf` file in addition to the `agent_<id>.conf` one. HJaving a look your file, I've seen that:

```
AGENT_NAME=root
```

This is wrong, and should be `cygnusagent` instead of `root`. As described in the comments:

```
# Name of the agent. The name of the agent is not trivial, since it is
# the base for the Flume parameters naming conventions, e.g. it appears
# in .sources.http-source.channels=...
```

Comment: In the comments i said that i implemented the changes. I did not updated my answer properly. It is now edited and i already had in the cygnus_instance_c1.conf the AGENT_NAME = cygnusangent

Comment: Ah OK, sorry. Maybe you could add the full log you get when running Cygnus as a service. If it is a large log, you may use a Github gist https://gist.github.com/