# My Cygnus agent doesn't create a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, fiware, fiware-cygnus

Good afternoon!

Following the documentation of http://fiware-cygnus.readthedocs.io I created my two conf as follows:

**cygnus_instance_1.conf** (EDIT: UPDATED AT 2017/11/23)

```
CYGNUS_USER=cygnus
CONFIG_FOLDER=/usr/cygnus/conf
CONFIG_FILE=/usr/cygnus/conf/agent_1.conf
AGENT_NAME=cygnus-ngsi
LOGFILE_NAME=cygnus.log
ADMIN_PORT=8081
POLLING_INTERVAL=30
```

**agent_1.conf** (EDIT: UPDATED AT 2017/12/1)

```
cygnus-ngsi.sources = http-source
cygnus-ngsi.sinks = mysql-sink
cygnus-ngsi.channels = mysql-channel

cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.channels = mysql-channel
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.type = org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.port = 5050
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.handler = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.NGSIRestHandler
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.handler.notification_target = /notify
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.handler.default_service =
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.handler.default_service_path = /
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.handler.events_ttl = 2
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.interceptors = ts
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.interceptors.ts.type = timestamp

cygnus-ngsi.channels.mysql-channel.type = memory
cygnus-ngsi.channels.mysql-channel.capacity = 1000
cygnus-ngsi.channels.mysql-channel.transactionCapacity = 100


cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mysql-sink.mysql_port = 3306
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mysql-sink.mysql_host = localhost
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mysql-sink.enable_grouping = true
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mysql-sink.mysql_password = *********
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mysql-sink.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSIMySQLSink
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mysql-sink.batch_timeout = 10
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mysql-sink.mysql_username = username
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mysql-sink.batch_size = 1
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mysql-sink.channel = mysql-channel
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mysql-sink.new_parameter = new_value
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mysql-sink.data_model = dm-by-attribute
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mysql-sink.attr_persistence = row
```

I previously created my subscription so that when the activity was changed, the previous entity was saved in MySQL.

```
    $ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://$IP_PUBLIC:1026/v2/subscriptions");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{
  \"description\": \"One subscription to rule them all\",
  \"subject\": {
    \"entities\": [
      {
        \"idPattern\": \".*\",
        \"type\": \"ExerciseAction\"
      }
    ],
    \"condition\": {
      \"attrs\": [
        \"startTime\"
      ]
    }
  },
  \"notification\": {
    \"http\": {
      \"url\": \"http://$IP_PUBLIC:5050/notify\"
    },
    \"attrs\": [
      \"startTime\" 
    ]
  },
  \"expires\": \"2020-04-05T14:00:00.00Z\"
}");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  "Content-Type: application/json"
));

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($response);
```

**cygnus.log** after update entity

```
time=2017-12-01T12:52:50.539Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=cdeca432-d695-11e7-9c51-fa163ec68c31 | trans=fe9234ec-055b-483d-876d-e15d442a0efe | srv=default | subsrv=/ | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=run | msg=org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner[160] 

: Unable to deliver event. Exception follows.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: begin() called when transaction is OPEN!
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:145)
        at org.apache.flume.channel.BasicTransactionSemantics.begin(BasicTransactionSemantics.java:131)
        at com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISink.processNewBatches(NGSISink.java:476)
        at com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISink.process(NGSISink.java:368)
        at org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor.process(DefaultSinkProcessor.java:68)
        at org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner.run(SinkRunner.java:147)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
time=2017-12-01T12:52:53.031Z | lvl=INFO | corr=8b61fc74-d696-11e7-a933-fa163ec68c31 | trans=ccb60fea-10f8-46eb-82fa-8864f9352e41 | srv=default | subsrv=/ | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=getEvents | 

msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.NGSIRestHandler[286] : [NGSIRestHandler] Starting internal transaction (ccb60fea-10f8-46eb-82fa-8864f9352e41)
time=2017-12-01T12:52:53.042Z | lvl=INFO | corr=8b61fc74-d696-11e7-a933-fa163ec68c31 | trans=ccb60fea-10f8-46eb-82fa-8864f9352e41 | srv=default | subsrv=/ | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=getEvents | 

msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.NGSIRestHandler[304] : [NGSIRestHandler] Received data ({  "subscriptionId" : "5a2150a4d3258a6d7c656d26",  "originator" : "localhost",  "contextResponses" : [    {      "contextElement" : {        

"type" : "ExerciseAction",        "isPattern" : "false",        "id" : "75",        "attributes" : [          {            "name" : "startTime",            "type" : "Text",            "value" : "30/11/2017 14:38:40"          }        ]  

    },      "statusCode" : {        "code" : "200",        "reasonPhrase" : "OK"      }    }  ]})
time=2017-12-01T12:52:55.546Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=cdeca432-d695-11e7-9c51-fa163ec68c31 | trans=fe9234ec-055b-483d-876d-e15d442a0efe | srv=default | subsrv=/ | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=run | msg=org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner[160] 

: Unable to deliver event. Exception follows.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: begin() called when transaction is OPEN!
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:145)
        at org.apache.flume.channel.BasicTransactionSemantics.begin(BasicTransactionSemantics.java:131)
        at com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISink.processNewBatches(NGSISink.java:476)
        at com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISink.process(NGSISink.java:368)
        at org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor.process(DefaultSinkProcessor.java:68)
        at org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner.run(SinkRunner.java:147)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
time=2017-12-01T12:53:00.548Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=cdeca432-d695-11e7-9c51-fa163ec68c31 | trans=fe9234ec-055b-483d-876d-e15d442a0efe | srv=default | subsrv=/ | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=run | msg=org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner[160] 

: Unable to deliver event. Exception follows.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: begin() called when transaction is OPEN!
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:145)
        at org.apache.flume.channel.BasicTransactionSemantics.begin(BasicTransactionSemantics.java:131)
        at com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISink.processNewBatches(NGSISink.java:476)
        at com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISink.process(NGSISink.java:368)
        at org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor.process(DefaultSinkProcessor.java:68)
        at org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner.run(SinkRunner.java:147)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
time=2017-12-01T12:53:05.550Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=cdeca432-d695-11e7-9c51-fa163ec68c31 | trans=fe9234ec-055b-483d-876d-e15d442a0efe | srv=default | subsrv=/ | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=run | msg=org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner[160] 

: Unable to deliver event. Exception follows.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: begin() called when transaction is OPEN!
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:145)
        at org.apache.flume.channel.BasicTransactionSemantics.begin(BasicTransactionSemantics.java:131)
        at com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISink.processNewBatches(NGSISink.java:476)
        at com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISink.process(NGSISink.java:368)
        at org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor.process(DefaultSinkProcessor.java:68)
        at org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner.run(SinkRunner.java:147)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
time=2017-12-01T12:53:10.551Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=cdeca432-d695-11e7-9c51-fa163ec68c31 | trans=fe9234ec-055b-483d-876d-e15d442a0efe | srv=default | subsrv=/ | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=run | msg=org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner[160] 

: Unable to deliver event. Exception follows.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: begin() called when transaction is OPEN!
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:145)
        at org.apache.flume.channel.BasicTransactionSemantics.begin(BasicTransactionSemantics.java:131)
        at com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISink.processNewBatches(NGSISink.java:476)
        at com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISink.process(NGSISink.java:368)
        at org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor.process(DefaultSinkProcessor.java:68)
        at org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner.run(SinkRunner.java:147)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
time=2017-12-01T12:53:15.554Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=cdeca432-d695-11e7-9c51-fa163ec68c31 | trans=fe9234ec-055b-483d-876d-e15d442a0efe | srv=default | subsrv=/ | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=run | msg=org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner[160] 

: Unable to deliver event. Exception follows.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: begin() called when transaction is OPEN!
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:145)
        at org.apache.flume.channel.BasicTransactionSemantics.begin(BasicTransactionSemantics.java:131)
        at com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISink.processNewBatches(NGSISink.java:476)
        at com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISink.process(NGSISink.java:368)
        at org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor.process(DefaultSinkProcessor.java:68)
        at org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner.run(SinkRunner.java:147)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
time=2017-12-01T12:53:20.558Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=cdeca432-d695-11e7-9c51-fa163ec68c31 | trans=fe9234ec-055b-483d-876d-e15d442a0efe | srv=default | subsrv=/ | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=run | msg=org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner[160] 

: Unable to deliver event. Exception follows.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: begin() called when transaction is OPEN!
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:145)
        at org.apache.flume.channel.BasicTransactionSemantics.begin(BasicTransactionSemantics.java:131)
        at com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISink.processNewBatches(NGSISink.java:476)
        at com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISink.process(NGSISink.java:368)
        at org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor.process(DefaultSinkProcessor.java:68)
        at org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner.run(SinkRunner.java:147)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
time=2017-12-01T12:53:25.559Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=cdeca432-d695-11e7-9c51-fa163ec68c31 | trans=fe9234ec-055b-483d-876d-e15d442a0efe | srv=default | subsrv=/ | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=run | msg=org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner[160] 

: Unable to deliver event. Exception follows.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: begin() called when transaction is OPEN!
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:145)
        at org.apache.flume.channel.BasicTransactionSemantics.begin(BasicTransactionSemantics.java:131)
        at com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISink.processNewBatches(NGSISink.java:476)
        at com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISink.process(NGSISink.java:368)
        at org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor.process(DefaultSinkProcessor.java:68)
        at org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner.run(SinkRunner.java:147)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
time=2017-12-01T12:53:30.561Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=cdeca432-d695-11e7-9c51-fa163ec68c31 | trans=fe9234ec-055b-483d-876d-e15d442a0efe | srv=default | subsrv=/ | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=run | msg=org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner[160] 

: Unable to deliver event. Exception follows.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: begin() called when transaction is OPEN!
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:145)
        at org.apache.flume.channel.BasicTransactionSemantics.begin(BasicTransactionSemantics.java:131)
        at com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISink.processNewBatches(NGSISink.java:476)
        at com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISink.process(NGSISink.java:368)
        at org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor.process(DefaultSinkProcessor.java:68)
        at org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner.run(SinkRunner.java:147)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
time=2017-12-01T12:53:35.568Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=cdeca432-d695-11e7-9c51-fa163ec68c31 | trans=fe9234ec-055b-483d-876d-e15d442a0efe | srv=default | subsrv=/ | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=run | msg=org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner[160] 

: Unable to deliver event. Exception follows.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: begin() called when transaction is OPEN!
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:145)
        at org.apache.flume.channel.BasicTransactionSemantics.begin(BasicTransactionSemantics.java:131)
        at com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISink.processNewBatches(NGSISink.java:476)
        at com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISink.process(NGSISink.java:368)
        at org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor.process(DefaultSinkProcessor.java:68)
        at org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner.run(SinkRunner.java:147)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
time=2017-12-01T12:53:40.569Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=cdeca432-d695-11e7-9c51-fa163ec68c31 | trans=fe9234ec-055b-483d-876d-e15d442a0efe | srv=default | subsrv=/ | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=run | msg=org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner[160] 

: Unable to deliver event. Exception follows.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: begin() called when transaction is OPEN!
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:145)
        at org.apache.flume.channel.BasicTransactionSemantics.begin(BasicTransactionSemantics.java:131)
        at com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISink.processNewBatches(NGSISink.java:476)
        at com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISink.process(NGSISink.java:368)
        at org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor.process(DefaultSinkProcessor.java:68)
        at org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner.run(SinkRunner.java:147)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
time=2017-12-01T12:53:45.570Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=cdeca432-d695-11e7-9c51-fa163ec68c31 | trans=fe9234ec-055b-483d-876d-e15d442a0efe | srv=default | subsrv=/ | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=run | msg=org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner[160] 

: Unable to deliver event. Exception follows.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: begin() called when transaction is OPEN!
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:145)
        at org.apache.flume.channel.BasicTransactionSemantics.begin(BasicTransactionSemantics.java:131)
        at com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISink.processNewBatches(NGSISink.java:476)
        at com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISink.process(NGSISink.java:368)
        at org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor.process(DefaultSinkProcessor.java:68)
        at org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner.run(SinkRunner.java:147)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
time=2017-12-01T12:53:50.571Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=cdeca432-d695-11e7-9c51-fa163ec68c31 | trans=fe9234ec-055b-483d-876d-e15d442a0efe | srv=default | subsrv=/ | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=run | msg=org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner[160] 

: Unable to deliver event. Exception follows.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: begin() called when transaction is OPEN!
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:145)
        at org.apache.flume.channel.BasicTransactionSemantics.begin(BasicTransactionSemantics.java:131)
        at com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISink.processNewBatches(NGSISink.java:476)
        at com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISink.process(NGSISink.java:368)
        at org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor.process(DefaultSinkProcessor.java:68)
        at org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner.run(SinkRunner.java:147)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
time=2017-12-01T12:53:55.574Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=cdeca432-d695-11e7-9c51-fa163ec68c31 | trans=fe9234ec-055b-483d-876d-e15d442a0efe | srv=default | subsrv=/ | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=run | msg=org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner[160] 

: Unable to deliver event. Exception follows.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: begin() called when transaction is OPEN!
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:145)
        at org.apache.flume.channel.BasicTransactionSemantics.begin(BasicTransactionSemantics.java:131)
        at com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISink.processNewBatches(NGSISink.java:476)
        at com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISink.process(NGSISink.java:368)
        at org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor.process(DefaultSinkProcessor.java:68)
        at org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner.run(SinkRunner.java:147)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
time=2017-12-01T12:54:00.575Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=cdeca432-d695-11e7-9c51-fa163ec68c31 | trans=fe9234ec-055b-483d-876d-e15d442a0efe | srv=default | subsrv=/ | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=run | msg=org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner[160] 

: Unable to deliver event. Exception follows.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: begin() called when transaction is OPEN!
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:145)
        at org.apache.flume.channel.BasicTransactionSemantics.begin(BasicTransactionSemantics.java:131)
        at com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISink.processNewBatches(NGSISink.java:476)
        at com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISink.process(NGSISink.java:368)
        at org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor.process(DefaultSinkProcessor.java:68)
        at org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner.run(SinkRunner.java:147)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
time=2017-12-01T12:54:05.576Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=cdeca432-d695-11e7-9c51-fa163ec68c31 | trans=fe9234ec-055b-483d-876d-e15d442a0efe | srv=default | subsrv=/ | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=run | msg=org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner[160] 

: Unable to deliver event. Exception follows.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: begin() called when transaction is OPEN!
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:145)
        at org.apache.flume.channel.BasicTransactionSemantics.begin(BasicTransactionSemantics.java:131)
        at com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISink.processNewBatches(NGSISink.java:476)
        at com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISink.process(NGSISink.java:368)
        at org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor.process(DefaultSinkProcessor.java:68)
        at org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner.run(SinkRunner.java:147)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
time=2017-12-01T12:54:10.580Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=cdeca432-d695-11e7-9c51-fa163ec68c31 | trans=fe9234ec-055b-483d-876d-e15d442a0efe | srv=default | subsrv=/ | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=run | msg=org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner[160] 

: Unable to deliver event. Exception follows.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: begin() called when transaction is OPEN!
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:145)
        at org.apache.flume.channel.BasicTransactionSemantics.begin(BasicTransactionSemantics.java:131)
        at com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISink.processNewBatches(NGSISink.java:476)
        at com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISink.process(NGSISink.java:368)
        at org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor.process(DefaultSinkProcessor.java:68)
        at org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner.run(SinkRunner.java:147)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
time=2017-12-01T12:54:15.588Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=cdeca432-d695-11e7-9c51-fa163ec68c31 | trans=fe9234ec-055b-483d-876d-e15d442a0efe | srv=default | subsrv=/ | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=run | msg=org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner[160] 

: Unable to deliver event. Exception follows.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: begin() called when transaction is OPEN!
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:145)
        at org.apache.flume.channel.BasicTransactionSemantics.begin(BasicTransactionSemantics.java:131)
        at com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISink.processNewBatches(NGSISink.java:476)
        at com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISink.process(NGSISink.java:368)
        at org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor.process(DefaultSinkProcessor.java:68)
        at org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner.run(SinkRunner.java:147)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Can someone help me and tell me why the connection between my Cygnus and MySQL does not work?
Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Which version of Cygnus are you running? BTW, where did you found `es.tid.fiware.fiwareconnectors.cygnus...` package names in the documentation? Because such package names changed long time ago to `com.telefonica.iot.cygnus...` :)

Comment: Thank you frb for your response!!!
For the agent_1.conf I followed this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30511082/cygnus-not-presisting-data-on-mysql-database , I think that this versión is outdated.
I have the last version of Cygnus on my Fiware Lab installed.
Now I have changed my agent_1.conf (I edit the post) but my agent doesn't create a database after I updated my entity.
Thank you for your help!!

Comment: I'' recommend you to follow the official [doc](http://fiware-cygnus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). In the meantime, can you edit the post by putting the last configuration, and the logs you are obtaining?

Comment: Thank you frb for your response!
My last configuration is already in this post. When I try to find my cygnus.log on /var/log/cygnus/ I can't find it, the dir is empty.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Hello! I updated my post with a new configuration, but it makes nothing, I put cygnus.log.
Thanks!!

Comment: Can you provide your Cygnus version? I think `rpm -qa | grep cygnus` will tell you.

Comment: Thank you frb for your response!!
My cygnus version is cygnus-0.13.0-0.g0c6765f.x86_64 . I apreciate your help!!.

Comment: That's a very old version of Cygnus. I'll recommend you to uninstall it by following [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40369143/error-with-fiware-cygnus-installation-via-yum), and the installing the latest, using `yum install cygnus-ngsi`. Before uninstalling, backup your configuration, it is still valid ;)

Comment: Hi, frb!
Thanks for your answer, I installed the latest version of Cygnus

cygnus-ngsi-1.7.1-0.g9df0d4d.x86_64
cygnus-common-1.7.1-0.g9df0d4d.x86_64

I have re-used the configuration that I have attached to this Post, but when I update one of my entities, the information is not transferred to my MySQL database. I updated the question with the new log that I got after running sudo service cygnus start 1

Best regards!

Answer (score 1):

According to your log, there is a bug in the configuration. This line:

```
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.interceptors.NGSIGroupingInterceptor
```

Must be:

```
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.interceptors.NGSIGroupingInterceptor$Builder
```

In addition, you must grant the file within this variable exists:

```
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.grouping_rules_conf_file = /Applications/apache-flume-1.4.0-bin/conf/grouping_rules.conf
```

Anyway, that's for using Grouping Interception, which is an advanced feature (and also a deprecated feature; Name Mappings are recommended, instead). Thus, my recommendation is to remove those lines and only preserve the timestamping interception:

```
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.interceptors = ts
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.interceptors.ts.type = timestamp
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response. I have edited my agent_1.conf following your instructions (I have edited the post with the new configuration).
I have re-executed my agent as a service, I have attached the new log.
Unfortunately, the historical ones are not transferred to MySQL.
Thank you very much for your cooperation!

Comment: Good, now Cygnus log does not show any error. What I'm missing in the logs are notifications coming from Orion CB. Did you created a subscription in Orion CB pointing to Cygnus? Did you updated any instance involved in the subscription in order the notification fires up?

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, of course I have created the subscription, I attach in this the log that I got after updating the entity.
Thank you for your collaboration!